# Only display output for a given time

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I just started learning c++ and am using codeblocks. I'm just wondering if there was a way to set my output to display for only a certain amount of time.
For example, I have the code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    cout << "You need to learn C++!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now when I hit build and run, it displays the code and says "Press any key to continue". I want to know if there is a way I can set a timer for that display to go away instead of pressing a key.
Thank you!

Comment: There's no reproducible behavior as you describe noticed [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe0c5bb715e3f04d)?

Comment: C++ does not know about a console, it knows only streams.  But, you might consider a delay (using std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s)), then 'over writing' existing text with by repositioning the cursor (using ansi term escape sequences OR ncurses) then writing space characters to 'erase' them.

Comment: The standard behaviour is the program exits. What happens after it exists depends on what ran the program, so I suspect the behaviour you are seeing is a Code::Blocks thing. Slightly more useful than the insta-vanish  console of Visual studio that befuddles many starting programmers and has them adding code into their programs to jam the console open.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the window is not the responsibility of the program to do, it's the user responsibility. Anyway, you could stop the program for the time you want using  for stopping the program and  for measuring the time you want it to stop. If you double click the .exe file generated after compilation it will automatically close after execution, otherwise you will have to close the window by yourself.

More information here, about the std::thread method: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/this_thread/sleep_for/

And here about the chrono library:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <thread>
 #include <chrono>


using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    cout << "You need to learn C++!" << endl;
    this_thread::sleep_for (chrono::seconds(3));
    cout<<"Program finished!";
    return 0;
}
```

You could also use `chrono::miliseconds` or `chrono::minutes` or `chrono::hours`
There may also be a platform dependent library for closing the window . You could have one for windows, another for linux, but anyway you shouldn't be worrying about that as a beginner.

Comment: Micronag: `sleep_for` is not a `std::thread` member. It is a free function. Macronag: If Code::blocks is holding the program open the timer will expire, the program will exit, and Code::Blocks will still pause and wait for input. I'm sure there will be a configuration option to turn this behaviour on and off, but I don't know Code::Blocks from a hole in the ground.

Comment: Thanks for the response Diogo. I believe I didn't formulate my question correctly. I was asking if there was a way to close the output terminal automatically (after the program is done executing). It seems a possible way to do this is to pass an exit command from the program to the terminal. But after doing some reading online, it seems like this could be a risky way to do things.